# Outlook ignoring IMG width attribute

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I'm having an issue with my email template, specifically how it is rendering in Outlook (2007 & 2010).

For all other clients, the images are correctly staying within the stated parameters (both CSS and HTML rules) but Outlook is completely ignoring these and the images are overflowing.

It's wrecking my head! Anyone have any idea where I'm going wrong or how to solve this? Below is an example of my IMG code.

```
<div class="block">
   <!-- image + text -->
   <table width="100%" bgcolor="#a1dbee" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="backgroundTable" st-sortable="bigimage">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <table bgcolor="#6db1e2" width="580" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="devicewidth" modulebg="edit">
              <tbody>
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                       <table width="580" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="devicewidth">
                          <tbody>
                             <tr>
                                <!-- start of image -->
                                <td align="center">
                                   <img width="580" border="0" height="auto" alt="" style="max-width: 580px; display:block; border:none; outline:none; text-decoration:none;" src="img/image-1.jpg" class="bigimage" mc:edit="featured image 1">
                                </td>
                             </tr>
                             <!-- end of image -->
                          </tbody>
                       </table>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
              </tbody>
           </table>
        </td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
```

SCREENSHOT: http://i65.tinypic.com/wufo01.png

Comment: Try using `width` instead of `max-width` and add this property `img { display: block; }` Hope that helps

Comment: @VincentG Hi Vicent. Where? I have both added in most places above already.

Comment: `<img width="580" border="0" height="auto" alt="" style="width: 580px; display:block; border:none; outline:none; text-decoration:none;" src="img/image-1.jpg" class="bigimage" mc:edit="featured image 1">`

Comment: @VincentG Thanks for the response, but that didn't work.

Comment: What if you put the width on the parent `td` as well ? max-width doesn't work with Outlook, maybe check this trick : https://gist.github.com/elidickinson/5525752

Comment: @VincentG It appears as if I HAVE TO specify height and width figures for Outlook. Only way I can get it to work. It's annoying as I'm coding this as an editable Mailchimp template. Makes it a bit more awkward.

Comment: @VincentG +1 thanks Vincent! I copied and pasted your code and it works, then I saw that I wrote `width="150px"` instead of `width="150"`.